Removing Spamassassin report from email message?
update: screenshot added showing the original message Forwarded in a new email. Replying to this message only copies the spam report into the reply. I don't know how I would reply to a false-positive (this is using Thunderbird so maybe that's part of the problem).
I have spamassassin running on a mail host. Sometimes it dumps messages into my spam folder which aren't really intended to be spam.
So, Spamassassin creates a report and forwards the original message in a new email.
If the email isn't spam, there's really no way to get the original message back (pic added below).
Does SA delete the original email or is it filed in some location unknown to me?
Is there a tool or option in SA to remove the report or somehow turn the message back into "not spam"?
Maybe there is a config option for this I don't know about because it seems like a super common problem.


I think you want to use report_safe 1 in your SpamAssassin configuration file.  From man Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf:
report_safe ( 0 | 1 | 2 )     (default: 1)
    if this option is set to 1, if an incoming message is tagged as
    spam, instead of modifying the original message, SpamAssassin will
    create a new report message and attach the original message as a
    message/rfc822 MIME part

This should be the default, so please modify your question to show your actual configuration if you're already using that setting.
With this configuration, spam messages received to my mailbox have a MIME structure like:

MIME segment 2 is the original message.  When it suits me, I save that attachment to my Inbox, and delete the SpamAssassin report message.

Thanks. report_safe=1 is set here. I don't see anywhere it may be different, like in a user location or something. I don't think I worded my question clearly so added a screenshot.

It looks like there is a forwarded message attached.  What happens if you click on that, @Nstevens?

Fyi, @Nstevens, that message is spam.  I'd be careful about clicking links in it, or you'll be likely to confirm receipt, and thereby get sent even more spam.

Heh, yeah thanks for the heads up. I just used it as an example of how SA is forwarding the original message as an attachment. The real false-positive in question is a little harder to redact.
